# Associating articles and tags efficiently

Tags: java, algorithm, collections, document-classification

So I have a List of articles and a Map <Article Tag(string), keywords(string[])>. For every tag (about 10 of them) we have corresponding words (about 80 per tag).
I need to iterate through every article and check if it has at least 10 of the keywords:
If yes then assign the article tag for it.

I have come up with this solution. I think it works fine, but 3 nested for-loops scare me and can affect the speed. If you have any ideas on cleaning up the code, I would appreciate the help.

```
private List<Article> sortByKeyWords(List<Article> articles) {
    System.out.println("STARTING TO FILTERING for array of " + articles.size());
    int matchCounter = 0;
    for (Article a : articles) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : keyWords.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Array name --> " + entry.getKey());
            for (String key : entry.getValue()) {
                System.out.println("Searching for word --> " + key);
                if (a.getContents().contains(key)) {
                    matchCounter++;
                    System.out.println("FOUND A MATCH");
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("MATCH COUNTER " + matchCounter);
        if (matchCounter >= 10) {
            a.removeAllTags(Tag.RECHTSGEBIED);
            a.addTag(TagDao.findByName(entry.getKey(), Tag.RECHTSGEBIED));

        }
    }

    return articles;
}
```

Comment: a.getContents().contains() loops through article for all iterations , you can split the words in article by regex or iterating char by char until spaces then look for if word contains in keywords.entrySet() it can increase performance.

Comment: @tknkrtl yes, you are right! thanks for the suggestion. Any ideas on maybe using stream()?

Comment: It will only change the syntax so its up to you. If you're working on same articles and keywords you can implement caching

Comment: `matchCounter >= 10` you could exit the two inner loops since you are not interested in the exact `matchCounter`. That should , at least for matching articles, speed things up.

Comment: @MrSmith42 my bad, i have updated the code. I need the key from map for tag name

Comment: Then, @MrSmith42 is even more right in that you don’t need to complete the loop. In fact, the updated code is invalid, as the `entry` is not in scope after the loop. That’s more than just a typo kind of compiler error, it’s fundamentally illogical to count all matches over all keys but then trying to ask for “the one” key.

Comment: @Holger yes ser, you are completely right, saved my day. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in this way:

1. for each to change Map <Article Tag(string), keywords(string[])> into
   Map<keyword(string), Article Tags(string[])
2. for each on all articles (a,b,c is inside this loop)

   a. for each on your article text -> count all same words

   b. remove words with count < 10

   c. for each to get all tags for remaining words from map from point 1.

It should be O(n^2) if my counting is good

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. 1) I have like 800 keywords in total (about 10 tags and 80 words for each). Would that be okay to swap a map like this? 2) Sorry could you clarify that more, i cant wrap my head around that(

Comment: you can just create a map where keyword is a key and value is tag list or array. That way when you need to get tag by keyword you don't need another nested loop you just simply get it by keyword which on time complexity is counted as "1"

Comment: In general it all depends on what that program is for. If it's just for class it's probably ok to leave it as it is now because if you won't scale that keywords/tags database the calculation time will be very low either way.

Comment: Also keep in mind that ```contains()``` alone have like 1 or 2 for loops inside it :)
It have 1 loop if it's .contains on ArrayList<String> 2 loops if its .contains on String

Comment: we use it to index news sites and collect all the news to sort them and display them to users (all legal). thanks, i will to put your advices in the code

Comment: @greybeard fair enough :D, fixed that little issue

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a maintainable specification of what is to happen:

Currently, you check keywords for every *article tag* in turn.
If enough matches for the current tag are found, all tags are removed and the current one is added?!
Instead, remove tags at the start of this article's processing.
If you want a single tag, process tags in reverse order, and continue to next article as soon as a tag is matched.

Otherwise, a *lexer* (table driven for flexibility) is an alternative to [Morph21's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74446958/3789665) to use a map.
And the way I understood the requirements, you need to check the number of keywords matched.